Android eSim implementation
Having issues in direct eSim installation implementation via app.
I've followed https://source.android.com/docs/core/connect/esim-overview on how to perform a direct installation of eSim via the app, and manage to reach the step where it will prompt the user to give access to perform eSim installation natively, but nothing happened afterwards. Is there a way to verify if an attempt to the SMDP was done?
I'm using cordova for this implementation
